# What does 'test al, al' mean?

Tags: assembly, binary-analysis, x86

I'm trying to reverse engineer a program and i found the following instruction:

```
test al, al
je label
```

what does these two instruction do ? Can someone explain please ?

Comment: `test` equals `and` but does not place the result in the target operand. However, like `and` it manipulates the zero flag (ZF).

Comment: This is a standard idiom to test if the 8-bit value stored in `AL` (the register that is the low 8 bits of `EAX`) is zero. In other words, it's checking whether a Boolean is true or false, and branching accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

In x86 assembly, `al` is the least significant byte of `eax` register, which is typically used to return values from function calls.

The `test al,al` is a bitwise AND operation between `al` and itself.

If `al & al` == 0, the zero flag will be set to 1.

`je` (or `jz`) instruction will jump to the address of `label`, if the zero flag is 1. Otherwise, the `je` will do nothing.

In short:
If eax == ######00 jump to label.